# Msbuild : Error: The OutputPath property is not set for this project

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I am currently trying to decouple a project and I am getting the following error

> The OutputPath property is not set for project 'MyProj.vcxpro  j'.
> Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination
> of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration=''
> Platform='x64'.  You may be seeing this message because you a  re
> trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified
> a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this
> project. [D:\Test\MyProj.vcxproj]

I added this to my project but it is not helping

```
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <Platform Condition="'$(Platform)' == ''">x64</Platform>
    <TargetName>MyProj</TargetName>
    <ResolveExportedSymbols>true</ResolveExportedSymbols>
    <ProjectGuid>{xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx}</ProjectGuid>
    <UsePrecompiledHeader>true</UsePrecompiledHeader>
    <OutputPath>D:\MyOutput\out\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Any update about this issue? Also, one question about this, did you use developer command prompt for vs to build the project?

Comment: I had a similar problem, but my problem was caused because I could not get VS to set the Active solution platform to be x64 with VS2019. I then manually edited the project file but guessed at what should be there. It seems there must be far more than one might naively think to be the minimum required. I copied what was effectively there for another project previously created with VS2017 and things worked out for me. Anyone know where some documentation can be located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

         <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
            <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
              <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
              <Platform Condition="'$(Platform)' == ''">x64</Platform>
            </ProjectConfiguration>
        </ItemGroup>
        
         <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
            <TargetName>MyProj</TargetName>
            <ResolveExportedSymbols>true</ResolveExportedSymbols>
            <ProjectGuid>{xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx}</ProjectGuid>            
            <OutputPath>D:\MyOutput\out\</OutputPath>
          </PropertyGroup>
 
        <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
       <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
         <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
      </ImportGroup>


        <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
        <ClCompile>
          <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
          <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
          <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
          <PreprocessorDefinitions>_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions) 
          </PreprocessorDefinitions>
          <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
          .....
        </ClCompile>
      </ItemDefinitionGroup>

.....
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
</Project>
```

**Then**, delete any output folder like `Debug` and then rebuild again.